# Strange Binding Issue with FlipView and TextBox

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm having a huge issue with `FlipView` and binding. I have a `FlipView` with a `TextBox` on each item. When I enter text in the `TextBox`, and then flip to the next item, the `TextBox.Text` value is empty. So is the next one. But on the fourth item (`Index=3`), it displays the text that I typed on `Index=0`. This continues on to not display on the fifth and sixth items, but again appears on the seventh item (`Index=6`).

So if on `Index=0` I typed ***Test*** in the `TextBox`, I see ***Test*** on the fourth and seventh slides (indexes 3 and 6). This can continue on forever.

To compound the problem, it follows the last entered text and then displays that on multiple of 3. So, if I now go to the second item (`Index=1`) and type ***Test2***, it will appear on `Index=4` and `Index=7`.

I've tried this across multiple projects and the result is the same. I don't have another computer in which to try it on. The results are the same across running it in the simulator, local machine and remote machine.

Here's what it looks like:
[image: binding error issue in flipview]

For me, it really simple to recreate. Just add a BasicPage and then to that page in the grid add:

```
<FlipView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="100,0,50,0" x:Name="TabFlipView">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBox  Width="400" Height="100" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"  />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

In the `LoadState`, add:

```
Dim d As New ObservableCollection(Of String) From {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}
        TabFlipView.ItemsSource = d
```

Then run it. In the first `TextBox` type some text. Flip to the 4th item. The text that you just typed in the first item is there in the `TextBox` on the fourth item.

If this is somehow machine-specific and you can't reproduce, how would I go about troubleshooting this to find and eliminate the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode = "Standard"`
```

in your FlipView.  This should stop the recycling.

See this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizationmode.aspx) for more information:

**Update based off of comments**

If you can avoid the VirtualizingStackPanel, the following may work for you:

```
<FlipView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</FlipView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: This works, but unfortunately it clears the entered text on any given `TextBox` when returning to it.

Comment: Yeah, that is a drawback as it re-creates the panel from scratch every time. One way to get around that may be to bind the `.Text` in `Mode=TwoWay`. Another way, if you have a limited number of items (due to a possible performance hit), would be to just not use a VirtualizingStackPanel and use the edited code instead in your `FlipView.  However, I'm not sure how 8.1 acts - this issue may have been fixed in this environment. YMMV.

Comment: Just tried it without the VirtualizingStackPanel. Perfect, exactly what I needed.

Comment: Does not seem to be fixed in 8.1 as well.